# How can fragment pass data to calling fragment

Tags: android-fragments

I have an activity with two fragments say F1 and F2. On clicking the list view of F2 , a new fragment is called say F3 (Its single activity multi fragments design).
I have back button on right side of dual pane layout. On hitting this button i need to pass data from fragment F3 to F2, so that F2 views are updated based on data received(something like onActivityForResult for activity to activity interaction).
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fragment` class has `setTargetFragment()`, according to docs:

> Optional target for this fragment. This may be used, for example, if
>   this fragment is being started by another, and when done wants to give
>   a result back to the first. The target set here is retained across
>   instances via `FragmentManager.putFragment()`.